# Python RSA Decryption is throwing TypeErrors

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, typeerror, precision

My RSA decrypt function:

```
def decrypt(ctext,private_key):
    key,n = private_key
    text = [chr(pow(char,key)%n) for char in ctext]
    return "".join(text)
```

is sometimes throwing a `TypeError` which tells that `pow(char,key)%n` provides a `float`. Why is that? I cant explain it myself and it would be interesting to know why.

For example it happens when:

> ctext = [513300, 369218, 473524, 473524, 500307, 509880, 264366, 500307, 337068, 473524, 264834]
> private_key = [-159317, 540767]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to figure out much from a tiny fragment of code. You are getting float results because your variable `key` is negative number. It is clear from the description of [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) that you will get float results, which is not what you want. You really should be using the 3-argument form of pow, and your exponent should always be positive. By using standard [RSA math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation) you can always make your exponent positive by adding an appropriate multiple of Φ(n). In your particular case, Φ(n) = (631 - 1) * (857 - 1) = 539280, so key = 379963 mod Φ(n).

You should correct the code that gives you a negative exponent.

Comment: Thanks alot i solved this issue with: `d = d % phi        
          if(d < 0):
              d += phi`